# C Standard libraries when reimplementing LLVM backend

Tags: clang, llvm

I've been reading the documentation on LLVM and looking at the code for different architectures (in particular SPARC) and there is something I don't understand.

As far as I can tell recompiling LLVM with all the right classes reimplemented would give support a new architecture that can be used by the clang front end.

But what about the standard libraries?

Are those generic and recompiled for the target architecture? What would be the right way to proceed in this case?

Just to be clear I'm interested in porting LLVM to a new arcquitecure and I want to compile a C program for it.

Comment: I guess, it depends on library in question, but they are mostly portable.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean? By portable you mean that they are arquitecture independant?

Comment: Yes, that they can be just compiled for given arch.

Comment: Ok, I'll check into it when I'm further along that problem.